# In Kotlin, does the presence of a custom setter affect the necessity of initializing a var property?

Tags: kotlin, properties, initialization, var

```
class Student (private val age: Int){
    var isAdultA
        get() = this.age >= 20
        set(value) {}

    var isAdultB // "Property must be initialized"
        get() = this.age >= 20
}
```

Hello,
I've encountered a situation where isAdultA compiles without any issues, but isAdultB gives an "Property must be initialized" error message. While I'm aware that isAdultB hasn't explicitly defined a setter, I understand that a default setter is automatically generated. What fundamentally sets apart isAdultA and isAdultB? Why is isAdultA viable while isAdultB isn't?

I would appreciate any assistance. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we use default implementation of accessors, then the compiler generates a backing field for us and gets/sets this field. In your example, the compiler generates `isAdultB` field and then the `setAdultB()` method sets the value of this field. `isAdultB` is never read anywhere. And because we have a field, we have to initialize it to some value.

On the other hand, `isAdultA` doesn't require to generate any field at all, so we don't have to initialize it.